# Image won't show up html + css

Tags: css, html, image

I'm trying to put two images (dowload and view) on top of another ones, here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 backgrounddownload backgroundview">
    <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img class="img-responsive" src="123.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 backgrounddownload backgroundview">
    <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img class="img-responsive" src="123.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 backgrounddownload backgroundview">
    <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img class="img-responsive" src="123.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 backgrounddownload backgroundview">
    <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img class="img-responsive" src="123.png"></a>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.backgrounddownload:after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
background-image: url(dowload.png);
}


.backgroundview:after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
top: 50px;
left: 35px;
background-image: url(view.png);
}
```

For some reason the second div, in this case the dowload.png won't load, and in chrome while inspecting all the .backgroundview:after is disabled; I guess I can't have two :after, but how can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the container `.backgrounddownload` `position: relative` which in that case you are positioning them in relation to the body. Adding `position: relative` to the container will give you control to your `absolute` elements.

Add this in your css:

```
.backgrounddownload {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5h0qe4n/)

**Update**

It seems I have misunderstood your question. In that case, instead of having 2 `:after` you can also use `:before`.

```
.backgroundview:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #fff
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5h0qe4n/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your input but it didn't work, I have the same problem even adding your line; I think you missunderstood though. I'm trying to add 2 new images over another one. Over <img class="img-responsive" src="123.png"> I want to add a download and view images, and always to stick there. In your example you added two but only one white square can be seen, that's the exact problem I'm facing. Here's a snapshot: http://i.imgur.com/AFUaeB1.png

Comment: @AndreiLorincz ok, I have updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: BTW, how can I make that the images that are on top (te view and dowload one) always stick in the same place no matter what? The background image can vary of position and size, since it's responsive.

Comment: The images should stay at the same place as long as you set `position: relative` to the container which is in your case `.backgrounddownload`. Or maybe I'm not getting your question. If you want you can create new fiddle to show me or another post for that problem and I would be happy to help.